# Do the chess puzzles (optional and skippable) give any rewards other than achievements?

Tags: alice-madness-returns

There are three chess board puzzles in [the chapter 4](http://www.ign.com/wikis/alice-madness-returns/Chapter_4:_Queensland). This challenge is optional and can be skipped after failing once.

[image: chess puzzle screenshot]

Do the puzzles count for game completion and are there other rewards?

**Note**: The PC version doesn't have achievements.